# I've sharepoint 2013 farm last updated June 2014

Tags: sharepoint-server, cumulative-update

Our SharePoint Farm servers missing a lot of updates to be installed since June 2014, because of that, I was not able to install
Security Update for Microsoft SharePoint Enterprise Server 2013 (KB4484443)

Answer (score 0):

First, verify you've installed [SharePoint Server 2013 Service Pack 1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=42544). If not, do that first.

Then deploy the latest Cumulative Update -- do not just deploy security updates due to the gap. You also need a CU applied to be in a [supported state](https://blog.stefan-gossner.com/2017/12/13/updated-product-servicing-policy-for-sharepoint-2013/) by Microsoft. You must apply at least the [April 2018 CU](https://support.microsoft.com/help/4018348) to be in a supported state, but I'd recommend applying the [July 2020 CU](https://support.microsoft.com/help/4484447) which will cover all of the necessary security patches.

Comment: I try to install July 2020 CU but gives me 'The expected version of the product was not found on the system '
then I use command .\ubersrv2013-kb4484447-fullfile-x64-glb.exe   PACKAGE.BYPASS.DETECTION.CHECK=1 
it starts installing then gives failed to install

Comment: Never use BYPASS. It sounds like Service Pack 1 hasn't been correctly or fully applied. Remember to apply SP1 for all products (SharePoint Server, Project Server, and any applicable Language Packs).

Comment: it is installed under all sharepoint and language pack